# Credit memo refund more than original invoice due to return shipping costs

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, creditmemo, refund

A customer returned his product (because he received the wrong one) using another shipper which costs more than ours and wants a refund for his product and shipping costs.

I try to refund this but the Magento system does not allow the credit memo to exceed the value of the original invoice. Even when I add it as an adjustment fee or whatever.

What would be the correct way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an operating issue.

His shipping cost has nothing todo with the order in magento itself.

Refund the order in magento fully. Do not try to exceed the order total. Simply refund in full.

Refund him the balance outside magento by whatever means is possible to you.

Remember to place a comment to the credit memo. 6 months from now you won't recall the particulars of this incident. It is best to comment on it for later viewing.